# fancybox and msg conflict - Object function has no method

Tags: jquery, fancybox, conflict, fancybox-2, msg

I have these two scripts working at on my page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox();
});
```

which are opening a lightbox with ajax content and the following:

```
$('.check_item_delete.edit').bind( 'click', function(){
    $.msg({ content : 'blah blah' });
});
```

which is a kind of modal script.

the triggering elements are those:

```
<div class="collum_full">
   <div class="journalbox_check" id="journalbox_edit_check-6">
      <div class="form_line" id="line_6">
         <input type="radio" class="check_item_undo edit" value="undo" name="edit_6" id="und_edit_6"><span class="check_name_undo">Vorversion</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form_line">
         <input type="radio" class="check_item_delete edit" value="delete" name="edit_6" id="del_edit_6"><span class="check_name_delete">löschen</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="journalbox_checktitles" id="journalbox_edit-6">
      <a href="/web/de/intern_journal_history/6" class="various fancybox.ajax" id="6" title="bla bla bla">(6) bla bla bla</a>
      <div class="footnote">
         <span class="footertext">Ver&ouml;ffentlicht von xxx vor 48 Minuten am 15.12.2012 22:56 (AR)</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine. But when I once opened the fancybox and then like to open the jquery.msg modal I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'msg'
> (anonymous function)

I'm working with http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js and the new versions of fancybox 2 and jquery.msg

How can I make this work?

Comment: show your html, specifically the html of this selector : `.check_item_delete.edit`

Comment: They do not conflict with each other ... see **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/jqueryMSGandfancybox_16dec12.html)** (I just replaced the ajax content with an image for simplicity) My bet is that your fancybox ajax call is triggering a js error that then voids the jQuery.msg, but hard to say without an actual link to the page with the issue.

Comment: You actually solved my problem. In fact they did not conflict! I was loading the jQuery.msg again wich caused the error. Im so dumb! Thank you so much!